# Can I modify NetLogo commands with variables?

Tags: netlogo

To start with **example**:

`to make-new-car [freq x y head ]
  if (random-float 100 < freq) and not any? turtles-on patch x y [
    create-cars 1 [
      setxy x y
      set heading head
      set color one-of base-colors
    ]
  ]
end`

yet I want to have more breeds for cars - not just one car breed. I also want to keep it simple and insted of doing **this**(first function is the same as one above):

`to make-new-car [freq x y head ]
  if (random-float 100 < freq) and not any? turtles-on patch x y [
    create-cars 1 [
      setxy x y
      set heading head
      set color one-of base-colors
    ]
  ]
end`

`to make-new-carSE [freq x y head ]
  if (random-float 100 < freq) and not any? turtles-on patch x y [
    create-carsSE 1 [
      setxy x y
      set heading head
      set color one-of base-colors
    ]
  ]
end`

and being **redundant** by repeating the same procedure just with different breed name I wan to do something like **this**(put breed-name as an argument and use it with create- command):

`to make-new-car [freq x y head breed-name]
  if (random-float 100 < freq) and not any? turtles-on patch x y [
    create-breed-name 1 [
      setxy x y
      set heading head
      set color one-of base-colors
    ]
  ]
end`

However Netlogo is complaining that `create-breed-name` is not defined. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to do `create-turtles` then `set breed breed-name`. Here's an example.

```
breed [ testers tester ]

to make-turtles [ breed-name ]
  create-turtles 1 [ set breed breed-name ]
end

to setup
  make-turtles testers
end
```

You can also do probably do something with `run` after constructing an appropriate string, but I think the above is more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for sharing >)

Answer (score 2):

Go with Jen's answer. It is, by far, the most straightforward way to accomplish what you need.

Just for the sake of it, however, here is one way to do it with `run`:

```
to make-new-car [freq x y head breed-name]
  let commands [ ->
    setxy x y
    set heading head
    set color one-of base-colors
  ]
  if (random-float 100 < freq) and not any? turtles-on patch x y [
    run (word "create-" breed-name " 1 [ run commands ]")
  ]
end
```

Notice that I put the commands that should be executed by the newly created turtle inside an anonymous procedure (using NetLogo 6.0.1 syntax) and then run *that* inside the string passed to `run`. You could also put everything in one big string, but then you would loose compiler checking, syntax highlighting, speed, etc.

But, anyway, don't do any of this. Use Jen's method.

Comment: uusefull, will definitely use this in my future explorations of NetLogo. Thanks